# How can I use "d.press( )" on python-uiautomator?

Tags: python, android-uiautomator

I'm beginner on python-uiautomator,

I'm trying write some code.

I only find this code "d.press(0x07)", It will print (0) on drives.
but I want to know other number i can used or use press can print out like:(a,b,c,d) on my devices?

[BTW I know ".set_text" this way but I want use "d.press()"]

> ## python-uiautomator

```
from uiautomator import device as d

d.press(0x07)
sleep(1)
```

"""

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator

```
# press home key
d.press.home()
# press back key
d.press.back()
# the normal way to press back key
d.press("back")
# press keycode 0x07('0') with META ALT(0x02) on
d.press(0x07, 0x02)
```

More codes defined here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_0

Comment: '''''''''# press keycode 0x07('0') with META ALT(0x02) on 
      d.press(0x07, 0x02)                                                                                                                             I know this but i mean why 0x07 = 0 , if i want 5 how can i use " 0x05 "?

Comment: According to the page I linked. Constant Value: 12 (0x0000000c) = 5.

Comment: According to (https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/Sending+Key+Events+to+your+Android+Device) ...Android KeyCodes List
The following is a partial list of some commonly used KeyCodes:

'a' - 'z' --> 29 - 54
'0' - '9'--> 7 - 16
SPACE --> 62
ENTER ---> 66
BACKSPACE --> 67
BACK --> 4
CALL --> 5
ENDCALL --> 6

Answer (score 0):

If using `uiatomator`:

```
from uiautomator import device as d
from uiautomator import Device
d = Device('adb id of phone')  # get from "adb devices"
d.press.home()
```

If using `uiatomator2`:

```
import uiautomator2 as u2
d = u2.connect('phone adb id')  # get from "adb devices"
d.press('home')
```